# validate-jwt policy in Azure APIM - troubleshoot

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I have a [validate-jwt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies) instruction in my APIM API policy (`<inbound>` section).

I am sending a hopefully correct token in a header and the request still fails.

What would be the way to find out from the APIM which specific JWT token validation check has failed?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to do the logging.

1. Enable Application Insights for APIM, set 100% sampling for your desired API and enable necessary flags (see  [Application Insights for APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights).
2. In the designated Application Insights instance, the JWT token issues are found if you query

```
exceptions
| where type contains "Token"
```

Note that type is different depending on what is wrong with the JWT token, but I am speculating that all relevant types might start with "Token..."

so you get something like

```
IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'https://sts.windows.net/(abriged UUID)/'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0'.
outerMethod
validate-jwt
```

Also, from App Insights' Application map one can click through to failed requests and drill down to exceptions arriving at similar log outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the JWT is in fact valid? To do this you can paste the whole token value to https://jwt.ms in order to decode the token to see if you are missing any information.

If the token is valid, I would suggest setting up [Application Insights for APIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights) if you haven't done that already and see if you can get any more relevant information from the logs there.

Comment: thank you. I have added my own answer with more details.